# String to ArrayList

Tags: java

App reads TextEdit value to String and then converts to ArrayList. But before converting it removes spaces between words in TextEdit. So after converting I get ArrayList size only 1.

So my question is how to get the real size. I am using ArrayList because of its swap() function.

```
outputStream.setText("");
        stream = inputStream.getText().toString().replace(" ", "");
        key = Integer.parseInt(inputKey.getText().toString());

        List<String> arrayList = Arrays.asList(stream);
        int lenght = arrayList.size();
        if (key < lenght)
        {
            outputStream.append(lenght+"\n");
            outputStream.append("OK");
        }
        else {
            outputStream.append(lenght+"\n");
            outputStream.append("Error");
        }

    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  As it is, the question makes no sense to me.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are converting the String to an ArrayList?  That is likely where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    stream = inputStream.getText().toString();
    key = Integer.parseInt(inputKey.getText().toString());

    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String x : stream.split(" ")) arrayList.add(x);
    int lenght = arrayList.size();
    if (key < lenght)
    {
        outputStream.append(lenght+"\n");
        outputStream.append("OK");
    }
    else {
        outputStream.append(lenght+"\n");
        outputStream.append("Error");
    }
```

That is my guess at what you actually wanted to do...

Comment: Thanks it was usefull. But after this I choosed char array which was easier than ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

The size and the length are different things.

You try to get the size when you want the length.

Use `arrayList[0].length()` instead of your arrayList.size().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse your String to an Array try:

```
List<String> arrayList = Arrays.asList(stream.split(","));
```

(this example expects that your text is a comma separated list)

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList()` expect an array as paramter not just a String. A String is like an array of String of size 1 thats why your list is always of size 1. If you want to Store the words of your String use :

```
Arrays.asList(stream.split(" "));  //Don't use replace method anymore
```